# Is ({1, 0}, ⊕, ∨) a field? and Is ({1, 0}, ⊕, ∧) a field?

Tags: logic, field-theory, propositional-calculus

1 and 0 denote the logical statements True and False.
These two questions are for homework so would rather an answer that could help explain it to me then just a straight answer. Thanks to anyone who is able to help.

Comment: And what does $\oplus$ mean for logical statements?

Comment: Exclusive or, pretty much means: one or the other but not both.

Comment: Ok, so you need to check various axioms. Which ones are giving you trouble?

Comment: there is only one field with $2$ elements

Comment: check the distributivity of $0 \lor (a \oplus b)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first structure is not a field because the distributive law fails to hold. If you use more familiar notation (where T is a 0 and F is a 1) then we get that $0 \cdot 1  = 1$, which seems to imply that perhaps the distributive law is violated.  We can show this by computing $(T+T) \vee T$ in two ways and we get two different answers: $F \vee T = T$, and if we use the distributive law we get $(T \vee T)$ $+$ $(T \vee T)$  $= T+T=F$, a contradiction.

The second structure is the field $\mathbb{F}_2$ (which is the unique field of order 2) since the AND operation is essentially binary multiplication.